# why should I require all modules on every files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The default approach I often see is:

```
// repeat this in all files
var express  = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var async    = require('async');
...
```

But in my NodeJS apps I'm doing this:

```
// include this only on the server file
_express  = require('express');
_mongoose = require('mongoose');
_async    = require('async');
...
```

I prefer to use `_` prefix to identify libs/modules and I don't use `var` because I don't want to repeat the require/setup of all packages on every file of my application.

This way I can `require()` modules only one time on server.js file and use it anywhere.

Is this a bad idea?

Comment: I think it is "bad practice" to keep dependencies globally. Not that there isn't a preferential case (because it *might* be so darn handy to have a global alias to something used everywhere all the time), but do it with prudence - and not as the default choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modules are cached in nodejs. It is best practice to require where needed.

From the node.js docs:

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be
>   executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it,
>   "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive
>   dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: can you better explain this? is this about memory overhead? for example, mongoose... I need to require the module and connect it always? is this a good practice?

Comment: You connect only once. When you need to use mongoose in your other modules you do `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` and you get the same mongoose object with your connection. You can test this by doing `console.log(mongoose.connection);` in your module.

Comment: It should be noted that you can make additional connections to mongoose with `mongoose.createConnection`. The default connection (`mongoose.connection`) is the connection made with `mongoose.connect`

Answer (score 1):

In your front-end development (in case it's not just a server-side node question) you could surely make your requires on a base or main js and leave them referenced globally by appending them to the window, the document or any other highly-scoped objects but the best practice would be to require and load modules only when they are needed.